# WPF - Ironpython - How to destroy a frame

Tags: wpf, user-interface, ironpython

I am wondering how you can define a click event handler to destroy a window in Ironpython using xaml.  The Tkinter command is:

```
self.Parent.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.Close()
```

will shutdown the window and destroy it.